# Fade In Div After Other Div is loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to fade in my menu bar after an empty div is loaded (there is a large background image in the empty div). That image takes a second or two to load so I need the menu to fade in after the image (div) is loaded.

Here's my jquery:

```
$(.top-bg).ready(function() {
  $(".top-bar").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

(Document .ready doesn't give the  proper effect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that directly on that `div`.

Instead, create an in-memory image element, and set its source to the source of the background image;
then you can attach your function to the `img`'s load event:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $('.top-bg').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)/g, '');

    img.onload = function(){
      $(".top-bar").fadeIn(1000);
    };
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BPeG2/

Comment: It's not working... but I could be doing something wrong, though.

Comment: @Connor - You have to put all this in `$(document).ready()`. I added it to my answer.

Comment: for him there could be a path issue... just a thought

Answer (score 1):

you cannot wait for a load event attached directly to the div: you should instead load the image at `domready` event and then fadein the div itself. Also consider that you should check if the image is in `complete` state (if it's already cached)

try something like

```
$(function() {   // on dom ready event

   var div = $(".top-bar"),
       src = "url-to-your-image",
       tmp = $('<img />');

   tmp.one('load', function() { div.fadeIn(1000) })  /* one: it need to be 
                                                        executed one time only */
      .attr('src', src);

   if (tmp.get(0).complete) {
      tmp.trigger('load');
   }
});
```

Comment: No luck... do I need to put the image source in there somewhere?

Comment: .css(background-image) returns also url(...). try to write the url to the image instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    var tmp = $('<img src="relative_path_to_image" />');

    tmp.load(function() {
        $(".top-bar").fadeIn(1000);
        tmp.remove();
    });
});
```